# Rendering partials - No such method 'keys'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Following code:

```
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', f.object %>
```

where f.object is instance of a class called 'User'.

in an erb file is raising an error about not finding method 'keys' in the User object.

What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter to render, locals is a map that specifies the variables that would be available in the partial that will be rendered. Api Doc: 
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Template/render
Here, we are passing a User instance instead of the map Rails is expecting. When executing the code to render the partial, Rails is trying to use the User object as a map, hence the error about not finding the method 'keys'.

What I really needed was this -

```
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
```

where object is a variable the _error_messages.html.erb partial is expecting. This resolved the error.